# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited main()

Tags: python, async-await

Я только начал разбираться с библиотекой для игры Geometry Dash (gd.py, документация, если кому интересно: https://gdpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#id1) и когда запускаю функцию для получения информации об уровне, то происходит ошибка:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited main()

помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку, не могу её ни как исправить, заранее спасибо! Вот код:

```
import gd

client = gd.Client()

async def main():
level = await client.get_level(30029017)
# <Level id=30029017 name='VorteX' ...>

# some counters
total = 0
count = 0

# for each comment on the level, add its rating to total and increment count
for comment in await level.get_comments(amount=-1):  # all comments
    count += 1
    total += comment.rating

print('Average rating/comment on {0!r}: {1:.2f}.'.format(level.name, total / count))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Поправьте отступы, а то не понятно, где заканчивается `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это выводится из-за того, что `main` у вас сопрограмма (`async def`), но вы её никогда не вызываете с помощью `await`. Ведь сопрограмма при вызове как функция, просто круглыми скобками `()`, возвращает `<coroutine object main at 0x...>` и не выполняет код, который вы в ней написали, что не особенно полезно. Для того, чтобы получить от неё полезный результат, нужно использовать конструкцию `await main()`, но её можно использовать только внутри сопрограммы. Это можно обойти, вызвав её с помощью [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run):

```py
>>> import asyncio
>>> async def test():
...     print('Hello')
... 
>>> test()
<stdin>:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'test' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
<coroutine object test at 0x000001D47E7C4CF0>  # ничего не печатается
>>> asyncio.run(test())
Hello  # теперь работает
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @Evdok, если этот ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как [**принятый**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (галка напротив ответа).