мне выдает ошибку при использовании команды старт, и не добавляет меня в бд, хотя раньше все работало(aiogram)
Когда я пишу команду "старт" мне выдает ошибку и не добавляет в бд, вот ошибка:
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'add_user' was never awaited
   return await wrapped()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

вот код:
from database.models import async_session
from database.models import User, Ticket
from sqlalchemy import select, update, delete, desc
from datetime import datetime


async def add_user(tg_id):
    async with async_session() as session:
        user = await session.scalar(select(User).where(User.tg_id == tg_id))

        if not user:
            session.add(User(tg_id=tg_id))
            await session.commit()
        elif user.name:
            return True
        return False


async def edit_user(tg_id, name, username=None):
    async with async_session() as session:
        user = await session.execute(update(User).where(User.tg_id == tg_id).values(name=name,
                                                                                    username=username))
        await session.commit()


async def add_ticket(text, tg_id):
    async with async_session() as session:
        user = await session.scalar(select(User).where(User.tg_id == tg_id))
        session.add(Ticket(text=text, user=user))
    await session.commit()


async def get_tickets():
    async with async_session() as session:
        tickets = await session.scalars(select(Ticket))
        return tickets


async def get_ticket(ticket_id):
    async with async_session() as session:
        ticket = await session.scalar(select(Ticket).where(Ticket.id == ticket_id))
        return ticket


async def get_user(u_id):
    async with async_session() as session:
        user = await session.scalar(select(User).where(User.id == u_id))
        return user


async def delete_ticket(ticket_id):
    async with async_session() as session:
        await session.execute(delete(Ticket).where(Ticket.id == ticket_id))
        await session.commit()

и команда старт
from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery, ReplyKeyboardRemove


from database import request as rq
from Key import new_ticket, cancellation
user = Router()


class Process(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    question = State()
    question2 = State()


@user.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    user = rq.add_user(message.from_user.id)
    if not user:
        await message.answer('Введите ваше имя')
        await state.set_state(Process.name)
    else:
        await message.answer('Отправить запрос можно по кнопке ниже!', reply_markup=new_ticket)



@user.message(Process.name)
async def get_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(name=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Process.question)
    await message.answer('yfgbibnt cdjt bz')


@user.message(Process.question)
async def get_question(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    user = await state.get_data()
    await rq.edit_user(message.from_user.id,
                       user['name'],
                       message.from_user.username)
    await rq.add_ticket(message.text, message.from_user.id)
    await message.answer('ffbfbfbfccffbcfbfcbk;llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll'
                         'llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll'
                         'llllllllllllllllllllllll')


@user.callback_query(F.data == 'cancellation')
async def cancellation1(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await callback.answer()
    await callback.message.edit_text('действие отменено')
    await state.clear()


@user.message(F.text == 'Новый запрос')
async def new_question(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Process.question2)
    await message.answer('Напишите свой запрос', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove() and cancellation)


@user.message(Process.question2)
async def get_question(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await rq.add_ticket(message.text, message.from_user.id)
    await message.answer('Ваше обращение отправлено, ответ будет в течении часа', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    await state.clear()


https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1537717 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1327154

Вы запускайте корутину, но не дожидайтесь её завершения.
Замените:
@user.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    user = rq.add_user(message.from_user.id)

на:
@user.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    user = await rq.add_user(message.from_user.id)

